# AMD Interwave audio fx

Tags: ibm-pc, audio

I hope it's retro enough. Does anyone have any info on how AMD Interwave did sound effects?

I'm mostly interested in reverb, but others would be nice to know about as well. The question is specifically about this chip - reverb implementation in general has been explained nicely a million times already.

Comment: At what level of detail you need the answer? Because at high level, it just implements reverb just with generic delay.

Comment: Are you asking about the Am78C201? AFAIR it''s simply an all in one single chip FM Synthesizer with local memory interface for tables/sound/commands to be played

Comment: @Raffzahn It definitely isn't an FM synthesizer. It only plays back PCM sample data from memory.

Comment: @Justme so it's a kind of a primitive reverb, a few channels playing the same sample later and quieter, nowhere near the quality of say a convolution reverb? Makes me wonder why didn't they do it on the original GUS, doesn't seem hard to implement at a first glance?

Comment: @Justme well, yes, should have read wave table. [AM78C201/2](https://dosdays.co.uk/media/amd/InterWave%20Am78C201.pdf)

Comment: @Anton No there is a special processing path for getting convolutional delays to the played audio, which the original GF1 did not have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AMD Interwave has an on-chip effects processor, which can provide up to 8 channels of delay-based effects.

So 8 channels out of the 32 can be allocated for effects. A voice on a normal playback channel can play audio from memory and send that audio to an effects channel. The effects channel takes in data from the normal channels sent to it and can write the played data back into memory, to be played back later by the effects channel.

The delay is specified in number of samples and can be modulated with an LFO for further variation in the delay to provide chorus and flange effects.

The effect channel output can be fed back into effect channel input after selectable attenuation, which is how echo and reverb type effects work to get the required delay and volume change before hearing the audio again.